# uitableview setbackgroundcolor not setting the color in UITableViewStyleGrouped table

Tags: ios6

in iOS 6

[uitableview setBackgroundColor:] not setting the color when table style is UITableViewStyleGrouped

instead the default striped background is seen.

How should we set the background of the table if the style is UITableViewStyleGrouped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = TTSTYLEVAR(mainPageBackground);
self.tableView.separatorColor   = TTSTYLEVAR(mainPageBackground);
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Fixed it for me. You'll have to be careful of what other impacts this might have though.

Comment: how will this impact iOS 5 and iOS 4?

Comment: i haven't seen any, but if you are unsure you can always block it off with something like: if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0)

Comment: This always happen as long as you build the app by Xcode 4.5. I have a iOS 5 project and this problem also exists. Using "self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;" fixes the problem.

Answer (score 31):

```
[tableViewInstance setBackgroundView: nil];
```

Comment: Yes, this fixed it for me.  My syntax used was:
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView: nil];

Comment: please note this solution can give you problems in iOS 5 (if you remove the backgroundColor statement) because iOS will pick the default tableView background.

Answer (score 19):

Setting

```
[tableView setBackgroundView: nil];
```

gives me problems in iOS 5 so what I use is:

```
UIView* bview = [[UIView alloc] init];
bview.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[tableView setBackgroundView:bview];
```

iOS 5 and 6 compatible!

Comment: if you need a transparent background you can always use clear color where I use yellow.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple solution is to change the UITableView's background color in IB. I changed to "White color" for example and it worked again.

Somehow, leaving the background color "default" makes iOS 6 to not bother with any other color setting made in the code.

Comment: Worked like a charm.. simple & backwards compatible, thanks Sebastian!

Answer (score 3):

I would caution setting the backgroundView to nil. In my experience this causes a pronounced rendering performance hit during user scrolling under the latest XCode 4.5. Here was my solution to this problem that didn't impact scrolling performance:

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

    UIView *backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Seems like a good way to avoid any unintended consequences from having a nil background view.

Comment: I wouldn't set your backgoundView in viewWillLayoutSubviews but in stead set it only once in viewDidLoad and use an autoresizing mask. The way you implement sizing your backgroundView could give you performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

in ios 6 the method for grouped table view i.e the backgroundColor has been deprecated so instead use

```
[tableview setBackgroundView : nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been marked as answered but the following works as well :

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:233.0/255.0 green:233.0/255.0 blue:233.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundView:nil];
```

This way you don't have to set the for each tableView in the app. Thanks to author for the original hint !

Answer (score 0):

setting the background to nil does the job and yes it wont have any issues with the previous versions.